# Datastax DevCenter, fail to connect to cassandra on CentOS7 at VMware 10

Tags: cassandra, datastax, connect, cqlsh

I installed cassandra 3.11.3 on VMware workstation 10. 
also installed CentOS7 in there.

after that,  i installed datastax DevCenter on windows host pc. 
the windows version is 10.

but I can't connect to cassandra on VM.

this is casasndra configurations.

---

< cassandra.yaml >

```
- listen_address : localhost 
- rpc_address : 0.0.0.0 
- broadcast_rpc_address : localhost
```

< cassandra-env.sh >

```
- JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

---

Cassandra is successfully installed. and i can execute cqlsh on VM. 
and i can connect to CentOS7 using Putty.

but i can't connect to cassandra using devcenter.

---

I configured bridged network adapter of VM. Ping cmd of windows works fine.

IP of virtual OS(CentOS) on VM like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZthO.png)
devCenter connection properties like this. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GubBV.png)
what is wrong configurations? 
thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `rpc_address` to the VM's address will help you solve the problem.

Also, set `start_rpc: true`

Comment: Has this helped you @woojin park ?